# MS Access SQL Group By values of one column, select maximum value in the second column and value in front of it in the third column

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
| A | B  | C |
--------------
| 1 | C1 | N |
| 1 | C1 | N |
| 1 | C1 | N |
| 2 | C1 | N |
| 2 | C1 | Y |
| 2 | C1 | N |
| 3 | C1 | N |
| 3 | C2 | N |
| 3 | C3 | N |
| 4 | C1 | Y |
| 4 | C2 | N |
| 4 | C2 | N |
| 4 | C3 | N |
```

I want to group by `A` as below:

```
| A | B  | C |
--------------
| 1 | C1 | N |
| 2 | C1 | Y |
| 3 | C3 | N |
| 4 | C3 | N |
```

For each unique `A`, keep row with maximum `B` and `C` in front of that `B`. And if all `B` for a unique `A`  are same, but `C` has "Y" then then keep this row.

The code is in MS Access and I need the very SQL query.

Comment: I solved with this code.
```
SELECT DISTINCT
                            table.A,
                            table.B,
                            Max(table.C) AS C
FROM table 
INNER JOIN (SELECT
                                 table.A, 
                                 Max(table.B) AS B 
                     FROM table) grTable 
ON (table.A = grTable.A) AND (table.B = grTable.B) 
GROUP BY table.A, table.B;
```

Comment: Congratulations if that works. However, I tested and get "syntax error in FROM clause" when attempting to open query. DISTINCT and GROUP BY should not both be needed, use just one. Use a single tic mark for code in comment.